# Adding JSON to datatable

Tags: php, json, vb.net

I am trying to add JSON generated by a PHP script to VB.net data table but my JSON is not properly formatted (missing double quotes).

**PHP:**

```
 header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf8');
 $conn = mysqli_connect();
 $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM installations where hwid = '".$_GET["hwid"]."'");
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
 $data[] = $row;
 }

 echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($data), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
 json_last_error_msg();
 ?>
```

Generates this JSON which is missing additional double quotes:

```
 [{"idinstallations":"9","hwid":"74D435E5185A","naziv_racunala":"DESKTOP-0U5","naziv_instalacije":"prip","adresa_instalacije":"Vel","ukupno_artikala":"152","ukupno_dokumenata_d":"3","ukupno_dokumenata_arh":"0","ukupno":"20.50","prva_instalacija":"2019-06-14 05:25:45","licenca":"0","Opis_opa":"beb tipo","lastContact":"2019-06-30 14:05:43","version":"1.0.0.4\/a","dnevnik_summ":"20,50","arhiva_summ":"0","mod":"1","sync":"0","syncing":"","toMail":"xxx.ttt@gmail.com","licExpire":null,"teamviewer":""}]
```

This is my VB.net code which I am using to set JSON to datatable:

```
Dim webClient As New System.Net.WebClient
Dim result As String = webClient.DownloadString(http://www.something.com)
Dim json As String = result
Dim table As DataTable = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of DataTable)(json)
```

Comment: The only entry in the JSON entry is "licExpire" : null, which might be causing the problem. It shouldn't but VB.Net might be a bit more finicky about things :-)

Comment: @jeff If I copy paste this JSON in notepad and find/replace " to "" and copy that string as my `result` everything goes well and VB.net adds it to datatable.

Comment: Using `htmlspecialchars` will break your JSON formatting what you're seeing cannot possibly be a result of `htmlspecialchars` of a JSON string because all double quotes should have been replaced with `&quot;`. Try not doing that and sending a content type of `application/json` instead

Comment: The JSON, as posted here, is correct and deserializes to `DataTable` without problems.

Comment: @Jimi i get error: Exception thrown: 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException' in Newtonsoft.Json.dll

Additional information: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.

Comment: Try to copy/paste the JSON you posted here to a text file and deserialize `File.ReadAllText("[The JSON Path]")` (just tested it). There's an extra character at position `0` (right before the JSON). Here, it's interpreted as a white space. I don't know what you actually receive.

Comment: @Jimi I need to deserialize from website... Here is the priginal JSON: http://tposkasa.com/JSON/getMe.php?hwid=3065ECACDD89

Comment: That site puts a `<pre> </pre>` block before the JSON. If you cannot remove it from the source, replace these two line with `String.Replace()`: `json = json.Replace("<pre>", "") json = json.Replace("</pre>", "")`. Or something similar. Then it's all good.